# Why doesn't python closure work in this scenario?

Tags: python, closures, python-class, class-attributes, program-flow

```
class Example:
    text = "Hello World"

    def function():
        print(text)

Example.function()
```

`Example.printText()` throws this error `NameError: name 'text' is not defined`

Why doesn't `printText()` remember the class attribute `text`?
Does it have something to do with order python interprets the code?

Answer (score 0):

function is static
you need to use self to access the object property
like this:

```
    class Example:
    text = "Hello World"

    def function(self):
        print(self.text)
```

if you want to keep it static use:

```
def function():
    print(Example.text)


class Example:
    text = "Hello World"
```

Comment: "if i want to keep static? i don't get that"@eldad kdoshim

Answer (score 0):

use `@staticmethod` decorator to make the function static.

```
class Example:
    text = "Hello World"
    
    @staticmethod
    def function():
        # print(self.text) # raises error
        # because self is not defined
        # when using staticmethod
        
        # so you need to specify
        # the class name
        print(Example.text)

        
# now its working
>>> Example.function()
```

out

```
Hello World
```

extra information:

- variable `text` will be available for `every object` created using this class, and if you change `text`, will be changed in every object of the class.